# Copy whole folder with .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I try to copy the folder `FolderA` (contains html and php sites) which is in the same directory as the .bat script to another location.

**.bat Script**

```
copy FolderA C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA
echo "script end"
timeout /T 3 /nobreak
```

This creates a file `FolderA` on `C:\xampp\htdocs`, but it is NOT a folder! It is just a file with no extension and the file has html code from some of my files as content!?

How can i copy `FolderA` to `C:\xampp\htdocs`?
[image]

Comment: Ensure that `C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA` already exists! change `copy FolderA C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA` to `mkdir "C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA" & copy "FolderA" "C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. This will check for the folder and if it does not exist, creates it then moves the files to the newly created folder. Pretty much what @aschipfl had but in a complete script for you with checks.

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist C:\xampp\htdocs\folderA\NUL (
goto :copydata
) else (
    Echo Folder not found, creating it.
    timeout 2 >NUL
    mkdir "C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA"
    goto :copydata
)
:copydata
copy "FolderA" "C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA"
Echo Complete
timeout 5 >NUL
```

**EDIT:** Based on comment

Alright, lets go nice and simple then. This is the only line you need to accomplish what you want to do.

```
xcopy "FolderA" "C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderA\" /E /Y /F
```

Comment: Thanks,  i tested it but it does not copy folders, only files. I have the folder `scripts` in `FolderA` for example, and it is not copied.

Comment: Alright, Updated to a much simpler and fool proof way. Keep in mind it will overwrite any files with the same name in the location.